# Tableau integration with Civicrm

Tags: civireport

Can we integrate tableau with civicrm to get enhanced report functionalities?

Answer (score 5):

I use Tableau to enhance the reporting possibilities of CiviCRM.

Tableau can connect to many different data sources. I use a SQL connection to this, and this gives me full access to all the data tables in CiviCRM. I can then use Tableau to make interesting connections between different tables in an easy way.

I have not explored API connection, but I think that would be just as possible as SQL connection.

Comment: Thank you very much Flying for the information.I will look forward to the solution you have mentioned along with the api if it is possible.

Comment: Do you have Tableau installed already

Comment: not till now @Flying

Comment: @Koustav you just need a SQL username with the right access rights and then you are good to go.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can, I know one CiviCRM user that uses Tableau to get his data reports from CiviCRM. I expect he will answer to this post too, his name here is Flying

Comment: Thanks ErikH....Flying can you give me some link or tell me the steps to integrate?